# pyodbc.connect can't work in my python code

Tags: python, sql-server

i meet a problem when i use python.
Here is my code

```
server ="server"
user = "id"
password = "pwd"
db = "db"

conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL SERVER};SERVER="+server+";DATABASE="+db+";UID="+user+";PWD="+password)

conn_m = conn.cursor()
```

To talk about my situation. I have computer 'A', 'B'. When I connect my mssql from 'A' python code, it can connect. But when i connect my mssql from 'B' python code, it can't.(connect code is same)

There's an error about
'28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server] can't login ~~~

But when i connect mssql directly in 'B' computer with same id, pwd. it can connect.
I can't figure out why such problem occurs...

Comment: could you provide the full error?

Comment: Do you have sufficient access to the target instance using SSMS that you can see the Error Log node? Look in the Error Log for instances of Error 18456 (i.e.: login failures),  note the `State` number(s) that it reports, and compare them against the `State` numbers displayed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine why the logins are not working.

Comment: this is my full error
('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The user 'sa' could not log in. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The user 'sa' could not log in. (18456)")

Comment: thank you for @AlwaysLearning. follow your explanation, i can see what is the problem and I solve it. Thank you